# php deploy build folder only

Tags: php, php-deployer

I am currently using Grunt with [grunt-ssh-deploy](https://github.com/dasuchin/grunt-ssh-deploy) to deploy the build/ folder after the build is done via an archive, like this:

```
'ssh-deploy-release': {
        options: {
            localPath: 'build',
            currentReleaseLink: 'current',
            releasesToKeep: 3,
// ...
```

This is deploying the folder from the local path though, which I can do with deployer with:

```
task('deploy:staging', function() {
    writeln('<info>Deploying...</info>');
    upload('build/', '{{release_path}}/public');
// ...
```

but I want to deploy a  specific release build from the repo and use php-deployer but I can't find how to **only** deploy the build folder.

Is it possible to deploy a specific folder from the git repository with deployer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research and specially https://stackoverflow.com/a/25771130/1280034, I came up with a new deployer task that works for bitbucket (github users might want to use the `svn export` as said in the comment section):

```
task('deploy:folder', function(){
    $branch = env('branch');
    $folder = get('folder');

    run("git archive --remote=git@bitbucket.org:<repo> $branch $folder | tar xvf -")
    // then move the folder content one level
    // ...
});
```

It seems that it would also be possible to use a [git sparse checkout](https://briancoyner.github.io/2013/06/05/git-sparse-checkout.html)